# What does "внушать себе" mean?

Tags: перевод, значение

What does "внушать себе" mean?
The sentence goes as follows:

"Кровать подо мною подымалась, опускалась и вновь подымалась - плыла по синусоиде. Я внушал себе: "Ночью - нумера обязаны спать; это обязанность - такая же, как работа днём"

Answer (score 3):

"Bнушать себе" means to convince oneself, in a soliloquising way.

"Я внушал себе" = I was persuading myself.

Comment: @inkpenpen Instead of slicing and dicing this response, why not add your own?

Comment: @CocoPop I have removed incpepen's edits. (S)he indeed may want to offer a separate response.

Comment: Good one. I like your response — it's short and sweet!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd translate it as "to convince myself [of an (often irrational) idea]". A more idiomatic translation would probably be "to tell yourself a lie so many times you start to believe in it".
Imagine having a spouse who, out of the blue, starts suspecting you of cheating with a colleague, barista, delivery person, or a stranger who asked you for directions. That's the idea. They imagined you cheating on them regardless of a lack of evidence and convinced themselves.
A similar Goebbels quote: "A lie told once remains a lie, but a lie told a thousand times becomes the truth".

Answer (score 2):

“Внушать себе” means “to convince yourself”. The reason “внушать” doesn’t translate as “convince” is because in Russian “внушать” and “убеждать” are often interchangeable and mean the same thing. You can find both words as synonyms to each other in dictionaries.
If I tell you “Хватит внушать мне, что ты прав”, I mean “хватит убеждать меня, что ты прав” = “Stop trying to convince me you’re right”.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

My first response was to interpret this particular context thus: (something happened and) the storyteller is dead tired (if not tipsy or overwrought or frightened) and wants to **calm himself down**, **to talk himself into** falling asleep much in the same way as a hypnotist would. He repeats the words as affirmations and wants to instill them into his consciousness (and get the result) through persistent repetition.

Answer (score -3):

> ВНУШАТЬ.
>
> 1. что кому-чему. Вызывать, возбуждать по отношению к себе какие-нибудь ощущения, мысли, **заставлять чувствовать что-нибудь**. Он внушает мне отвращение. Внушать к себе страх. Внушать почтение. | Наводить на какие-нибудь мысли, вызывать какие-нибудь чувства. Его вид внушает мне опасение за его здоровье.

> 2. что кому-чему и ·без·доп. Поучать, наставлять, **заставлять усвоить** какие-нибудь убеждения. **Внушать мораль**. Всегда внушал
>    ему, что необходимо действовать вместе. Толковый словарь Ушакова.

Я бы использовал не persuading, а inspiring or compel:

The problem, that words *to persuade* and *to convice* are not translation of the word [внушать](https://en.kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5/%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#compel)

Inspiring:

> General sense of "influence or animate with an idea or purpose". etymonline.com

Compel:

> "to drive or urge irresistibly by physical or **moral force**." etymonline.com

Речь идет не об убеждении, с помощью доводов и аргументов с выводом, а о внушении — *идеологической установке*, определяющей дальнейшее целеполагание и управление.

Compel — тоже подходит, но с другой стороны, тем более, что компилятор —  программа кодификации с помощью *нумерных* кодов. А наш герой — нумер.

Герой внушал себе, что он — нумер, а все нумера должны спать ночью и работать днём, иначе они преступные номера — преступники.

Кроме того, там до идут строки про расщепление или деперсонификацию я, так что себе — это не myself:

*Ι* did an inspire/compel for *self*.

> Я — один. Или, вернее: наедине с этим, другим «я». Я — в кресле, и, положив нога на ногу, из какого-то «там» с любопытством гляжу, как я — я же, — корчусь на кровати.

> Я — один. Вечер. Легкий туман. Небо задернуто молочно-золотистой тканью; если бы знать: что там — выше? И если бы знать: кто — я, какой — я?

А немного ранее:

> Я гибну. Я не в состоянии выполнять свои обязанности перед **Единым** Государством... Я...

*Я - один. Или, вернее: **наедине** с этим, другим «я»* ~ I am alone(to United Polity) unified(?) with itself.

Нумер-единый-один — number/unit~united~uno/one

Единое Государство ~ United Polity.

Я — номер, и я — наедине с i-self.

И последнее, есть такой момент, что **нумерология** - это синтез религии и кодификации. Возможно, речь идет о каком-то унифицированном цифровом государстве, где нумера-цифры определяют границы человеческого сознания, об этом произведение.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149172/discussion-on-answer-by--what-does---mean); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @Cocopop я изменил, как такая форма?

Comment: @άνθρωπος Если вы имеете в виду *I did an inspire/compel for self*, то это предложение неграмматично.

Comment: @άνθρωπος **In my opinion**, it looks like you didn't quite understand the plot. It’s not about a “digital society” where numbers define people’s consciousness. The numbers in this dystopian society are used in the place of names (people are called numbers instead of people), since that’s one of many ways authorities dehumanize them. This is the story about a purely totalitarian regime on earth, and because it was written in 1922, the word номер *number* was spelled with у instead of o - нумер. So Д-503 was his actual name, nothing more. And numerology has nothing to do with the plot.